# Can an Object be declared static in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc

```
public static Connection connect;
    public static ResultSet resultSet;
    static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/java_dev";

    public ServerFunctions() {
        String Driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";            
        String DB_USERNAME = "lucky";
        String DB_PASSWORD = "lucky";

        try {
            Class.forName(Driver);
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Database Not Connected ! ");
        }
    }

    public static Boolean verificator(String username, String password) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement prepare = connect.prepareStatement(
                "Select * from users where username='?'&&password='?'");
```

Above is my code fragment. I am declaring the `Connection` and `Resultset` objects static so they can be called from the static verificator method.
also the verificator method is declared static so that it can be called from a different class as class variable just by using className.verificator(param, param).

It compiles and run when I test the class alone but then i get the NullPointerException error at the PerparedStatement Line whenever a call is made from different class.

Can someone Please help me why it is Happening ?

Thankyou

Comment: Some comments: If you're using prepared statements, you do not need to enclose string parameters in quotes.  You can instead use `Select * from users where username=? && password=?`.  If you're serious about doing user verification, then first of all know that you're doing it wrong, and there are many references online to help (such as http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).  Also, you do not make an "object" static, you are making your _reference_ to that object static--the object itself lives irrespective of how you reference it.

Comment: got you :) i corrected that stuff :) thanx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You said you declared the verificator method as static, so it can be accessed from other classes, and the verificator method is using the connection, which is also static.

The problem is that the connection is only initialized in the constructor of the object, so, if the constructor is never called, connect will be null.

You need to either initilize your connect variable in a static block, or verify if it is null before using it.

Comment: uhmmm ... Thankyou. I got it. When calling from another class it never gets initialised. 
Thanks a lost Sir

Comment: Nothing quite says "thank you" in StackOverflow like accepting the correct answer. And you're welcome. =)

Answer (score 2):

> Can an Object be declared static in java?

You can, but it's a bad idea.

```
public static Boolean verificator(String username, String password) {
    try {
        synchronized(DATABASE_URL){
            if(connect==null){
                Class.forName(Driver);
                connect = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
            }
        }

        PreparedStatement prepare = connect.prepareStatement(
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a `NullPointerException` because you do not initialize the variable. Try something like

```
public static ResultSet resultSet = new ResultSet();
```

or run the function wich initializes the variables **before** accessing them.

Answer (score 1):

This means that your `Connection` object was closed somewhere or not initialized properly (by calling the constructor). I would highly recommend not having static resources such as `Connection` and `ResultSet`, rather make them instance based and call that instance from a static method.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor is executed when an instance of the class gets constructed, aka when you use the `new` keyword.  By using the static `connect` variable before creating an instance of `ServerFunctions` the constructor doesn't get executed.

you can use a static initializer block to rectify this which will be executed when the class is loaded.

```
static{
    //code from your constructor here
}
```